# Tkinter: GUI won't appear because of loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

My Tkinter GUI won't appear because of loops, how can i make the GUI appear without disturbing the flow of the loops? Here's the code.

```
for record in data:

        # The rest of the code...
        
        # Datetime and auto validation for web automation 
        while True:
            convert_time_record = datetime.datetime.strptime(record[2], '%H:%M')
            date_now = datetime.datetime.now()
            time_val = record[0] == date_now.strftime('%A') and convert_time_record.strftime('%H:%M:%S') == date_now.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
            if time_val and record[3] == "Yes" and record[4] == "Link":
                print("time true")
                chrome.open(record[5])
                time.sleep(5)
                os.system("taskkill /im chrome.exe /f")
                break
        # Check if the method was by meeting ID
            elif time_val and record[3] == "Yes" and record[4] == "Meeting ID":
                # Open Zoom 
                subprocess.call("C:\\Users\\bryan\\AppData\\Roaming\\Zoom\\bin\\Zoom.exe")
                time.sleep(3)
                # Locate the center of the join button then move the cursor
                Click('join_button.png')
                time.sleep(3)
                # Write the meeting id to the text field
                pyautogui.write(record[5])
                # Press the enter key
                pyautogui.press('enter')
                time.sleep(3)
                # Write the passcode to the text field
                pyautogui.write(record[6])
                # Press the enter key
                pyautogui.press('enter')
                time.sleep(8)
                join_computer_audio_btn = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('join_audio.png')
                pyautogui.moveTo(join_computer_audio_btn)
                pyautogui.click()
    
    root.mainloop()
```

I've tried putting `root.mainloop()` inside the for-loop and while-loop but that will make the loops unable to execute the function.

Comment: Where is your tk code?

Comment: don't worry about that, it's on the top of the code, but i don't want to show all of my code

Comment: Try saying `root.update()` towards the end of the loop, still the GUI will freeze due to `time.sleep()`, use `root.after()` properly so the GUI wont freese.

Answer (score 0):

You should run `root.mainloop()` only once.
Using loops prevents the GUI from updating, therefore consider using a different thread to run the loop and send updates to the GUI from the other thread, or use an object for maintaining the state of the loop and use a non blocking function to get the state of the object and have it update and re-set the call with the after function of tkinter.

Comment: i understand what you mean, but i never use thread before. Can you show a simple code example?